# Find out which enum value is constructed

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I don't know if what I want to do is even doable but I'll ask anyway.

I want to find out which enum value is being constructed in this enum's constructor. 
Here is the pseudo code:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    VALUE_ONE, VALUE_TWO;

    private SomeEnum() {
        System.out.print(*some-reflection-magic*);
    }
}
```

So when I call `SomeEnum.VALUE_ONE` somewhere else I'll get "VALUE_ONE" on my `System.out`.

Don't ask why, it's just for fun :)

Comment: Does calling the [`name`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29) method not work?

Comment: or `System.out.println(this);`?

Comment: Nope, none of this works. For some strange reasons I get outputs for each possible value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want something printed out *every time* an enum constant is used, then the answer is no. Enum values are instantiated once (and in many ways constitute the quintessential singleton implementation on the JVM), typically when the `enum` type is loaded. This is why, when printing inside the `enum`'s constructor, you'll observe that all the values are being instantiated.

Comment: There is no "typically" about it: the JLS mandates precisely when all the enum members will be constructed. The rules are the same as for `static` class members.

Answer (score 4):

`System.out.println(this);` in constructor prints which `enum` constant being instantiated.

Example:

```
public enum EnumExcersise {

    RED(5) {

        @Override
        public String getHexVal() {
            return "Red Value";
        }
    }, BLUE(4) {

        @Override
        public String getHexVal() {
            return "Blue Value";
        }
    }, GREEN(3) {

        @Override
        public String getHexVal() {
            return "Green Value";
        }
    }, YELLOW(8) {

        @Override
        public String getHexVal() {
            return "Yellow Value";
        }
    };

    public abstract String getHexVal();

    public int getVal() {
        return value;
    }
    private int value;

    private EnumExcersise(int ipValue) {
        System.out.println(this);
        this.value = ipValue;
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
RED BLUE GREEN YELLOW
```

Comment: Well yes, whole point of this question is to get _ONLY_ `BLUE` when `EnumExersise.BLUE` is executed, not all possible values.

Comment: If that is what your question is, not possible. Enum constants are  static and final, so they won't be constructed on each call.

Answer (score 2):

Enum members follow the logic of `static` members of regular classes. They are all initialized at class initialization time, which happens at the moment when the class is first referenced by running code.

Answer (score 0):

**ALL** enum object values are automatically created once only on initial loading into the JVM:

```
enum SomeEnum {
    VALUE_ONE, VALUE_TWO;

    private SomeEnum() {
        System.out.println("Constructing SomeEnum " + name());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(VALUE_ONE);
    }
}
```

output:

```
Constructing SomeEnum VALUE_ONE
Constructing SomeEnum VALUE_TWO
VALUE_ONE
```

Comment: The output of this is: `Constructing SomeEnum VALUE_ONE
Constructing SomeEnum VALUE_TWO`